# This is a question on Computer architecture basically on logic gates

Tags: logic, cpu-architecture, boolean-logic

Question is
1) design a truth table for three processor when p1 is off then others are off or p2 is on and others are off
2) design a chip with minimum number of logic gates

Comment: Hello! Please refer to [ask]. Include what research you’ve done, what steps did you take.

Comment: ^  it looks like it could be a HW question and it’s okay to ask these type of questions. However, it is not okay to ask these type of questions without providing evidence of research or effort IMHO... Doing so will cause many to downvote and even flag your question.

Answer (score 0):

I can give you boolean expression, and I think it can't solve your both question easily!

As given statement1 : **when p1 is off then others are off**

you can give `!p1 -> !p2 && !p3`

then, you can simplify it. `!(!p1)||(!p2&&!p3)` is result

As given statement1 : ** p2 is on and others are off 2**

you can give `p2 -> !p1&&!p3`

also, simplify it then you can get `!p2 || (!p1&&p3)`

Last, combine both statement use given `or`. So, you can get `(!(!p1)||(!p2&&!p3))||(!p2 || (!p1&&p3))`

And then you can use it to draw truth table by use different value of p1, p2 and p3!